# Create a tree from a flat list

Tags: r, list, tree, reduce

Assume we have a list like the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "preserver"

[[2]]
[1] "person, individual"

[[3]]
[1] "organism, being" "causal agent"   

[[4]]
[1] "living thing"    "physical entity"

[[5]]
[1] "unit"   "entity"

[[6]]
[1] "object"

[[7]]
[1] "physical entity"
```

Obtained by as follows:

```
list("preserver", "person, individual", c("organism, being", "causal agent"), c("living thing", "physical entity"), c("unit", "entity"), "object", "physical entity")
```

Assuming that **each element of this list represents a level of a tree**, I'm looking for a way to **create such a tree**.

For example, in this case the output tree will be:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$o
[1] "preserver"

[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "person, individual"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "organism, being"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "living thing"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "unit"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "object"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "physical entity"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$o
[1] "causal agent"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "physical entity"

[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$h[[1]]$h
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]
[[1]]$h[[1]]$h[[2]]$h[[1]]$h[[1]]$o
[1] "entity"
```

Manually created from this list:

```
list(structure(list(o = "preserver", h = list(structure(list(o = "person, individual", h = list(structure(list(o = "organism, being", h = list(structure(list(o = "living thing", h = list(structure(list(o = "unit", h = list(structure(list(o = "object", h = list(structure(list(o = "physical entity"), .Names = "o"))), .Names = c("o", "h")))), .Names = c("o", "h")))), .Names = c("o", "h")))), .Names = c("o", "h")), structure(list(o = "causal agent", h = list(structure(list(o = "physical entity", h = list(structure(list(o = "entity"), .Names = "o"))), .Names = c("o", "h")))), .Names = c("o", "h")))), .Names = c("o", "h")))), .Names = c("o", "h")))
```

Regarding the solution: I was thinking about `Reduce`, but I still can not achieve a solution.

Also, I wonder about the possibility of representing this tree in other ways (i.e. not through this tremendous nested list; e.g. environments?).

Thanks in advance for your help.